# Use js variable in api request

Tags: javascript

I'm building an app where i want to use the users location in the api request.
I fetch the user position with

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} else {
    alert('It seems like Geolocation, which is required for this page, is not enabled in your browser. Please use a browser which supports it.');
}

function successFunction(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var long = position.coords.longitude;
  console.log('Your latitude is :'+lat+' and longitude is '+long);
}
```

I then need to use the `lat` and `long` variables in the api call `render(<Main source="https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[key]/[latitude],[longitude]"/>, document.getElementById('app'));`

I haven't been able to figure this out since i obviously can't just put the variable in the url

Comment: Why can't you just put the variables in the URL, just concatenate them in ?

Comment: Why can't you use the variable in the URL exactly as you do in the console log message?

Comment: This is JSX, right? How about [using curly braces](https://thinkster.io/rendering-variables-in-react)? `render(<Main source="https://api.darksky.net/forecast/{key}/{latitude},{longitude}"/>, document.getElementById('app'));`

Comment: Hi. Yes it is JSX, and thanks for your reply. I tried it out and it just returns `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/%7Blat%7D,%7Blong%7D`